# 2010: How to pass query string filter values to iframe

Tags: 2010, iframe, query-string, page-viewer-web-part

I have a page viewer webpart in a page where I want the ItemID to be updated dynamically when the page loads. Since I cannot filter values using query string, how can this be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you want to filter webpart by current username?

Comment: No by item id....

Comment: Is the ItemID you are talking about is the ID of the parent page having the Page Viewer Web Part or any other list item ID?

Answer (score 0):

It is better you use Content Editor webpart and an iFrame. The source of iframe need to be binded dynamically via javascript by passing URL and your `ItemID` in the query string.

Comment: Thanks Robert for quick corrections...will take care while answering other questions... :)